# Regular Expression to rewrite aspx?iid=

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite

I'm trying to make a regular expression that matches this using ISAPI rewrite(mod_rewrite):

```
www.website.com/product.aspx?iid=201
```

I've tried:

```
^(.*)/product.aspx?iid=201
```

And:

```
^(.*)/product\.aspx\?iid=201
```

Neither expression seems to match it.

Comment: glad to see that you updated the 201-values, that confused me :-)

Comment: That would have been an easy fix :), but it was just a typo.

Comment: The second RE looks correct to me; how does it not work for you?

Comment: Perhaps you should try matching with a very simple rule like (.*) so as to make sure that the problem is in the regex syntax and not elsewhere in your configuration.

Comment: @JMC 1) Can I see the link to "ISAPI rewrite(mod_rewrite)" so I can check it's features and how it works (is this Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite .. or another product)? 2) What URL (full url, including domain name, plz) you want to match and what are you planning to do with it? (as what you are trying to do right now is absolutely incorrect syntax in Apache or IIS)

Comment: @LazyOne - It's Helicon Isapi_rewrite http://www.isapirewrite.com/ . What's wrong with the syntax? The actual line would read: RewriteRule ^(.*)/product\.aspx\?iid=201 /product/productname [R=301,NC]

Comment: @JMC That's v2. As I understand you want to redirect this **exact** URL `/product.aspx?iid=201` to `/product/productname` (product name you will provide yourself) ... and for another id there will be another product name -- correct ?

Comment: @LazyOne - Right now I just want to redirect this one product id, but when I roll it out to all products I will use a mapfile.txt as part of the replacement expression.

Comment: @LazyOne - I think it's v3 because it uses .htaccess

Comment: @JMC Can you confirm for sure please -- as v3 has quite different syntax (almost identical to Apache) while v2 has it's own syntax. I will give you the rules for v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule below will redirect (301) from `domain.com/product.aspx?iid=201` to `domain.com/product/productname`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^iid=201 [NC]
RewriteRule ^product\.aspx$ /product/productname [NC,R=301,L]
```

You have to keep in mind -- Apache's mod_rewrite, Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite v3, IIS 7.x -- the `RewriteRule` directive (or it's equivalent in IIS) only works with "path" part of URL. If you need to  work with domain name, protocol, server port, query string etc -- you have to use `RewriteCond`.

The rule above is fully working -- I do have Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite v3 on one of my servers myself (IIS6, otherwise it would be IIS7 and standard URL Rewrite Module).

If you have any questions -- please ask, but most likely I will respond in few hours -- it's 3AM here :)

Comment: Thanks, I won't get to try it until tomorrow so no worries.

Comment: Good solution. I had to add a question mark ? to the end of the replacement expression to keep it from adding the query string to the end of the URL. It looks like this: RewriteRule ^product\.aspx$ /Product/productname? [NC,R=301,L] .

Comment: @JMC Hmm ... must be some special settings as it was not adding it when I tested on my server -- need to check the docs. In any case it is working fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
^(.*)/product.aspx\?iid=201
```

works here:

http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

So I would expect that to also work in IIS

If you were using java, you would escape your second solution like this:

```
"^(.*)/product\\.aspx\\?iid=201"
```

Maybe IIS likes that style of escaping (cannot test it here)